# Sort Laravel collection by value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, collections

I have got an array that looks like this:

```
^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#2057 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "pizza" => 2
    "cookking vuurschaal palma" => 1
  ]
}
```

does anyone know how to sort by value instead of keys in Laravel?

Comment: By just using ... [`Collection::sort()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sort)?

Comment: then its going from low values to high, any idea how to do it in desc? cuase sortDesc is not working

Comment: It is actually working: https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/63282965-0c93-41d9-99f8-bc428da96287

Comment: apperently there was an small bug but now is sortDesc() working

Answer (score 1):

`Collection::sortDesc();` worked for me